# What kind of privileges do i need to modify settings of an hardware device?

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm trying to give the privileges to edit the bitrate of a com port in device manager in windows 7 under an active directory domain to a non-admin user. Under local security policies(secpol.msc) i was unable to find the right option(i don't even know if it is the best way to do that...)
Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make changes within Device Manager, including changes to COM ports, is to make the user part of the local `Administrators` group on the computer.